# workflow sandbox model implementation

Tags: php, zend-framework, extjs, workflow, sandbox

I an planing on making a sandbox web application model for a workflow engine for different ordering processes.

I want to make it so that each element of the workflow can interact with an other element. each element should be Atonimously capable to figure out its workflow order and its correlations within the workflow, its current position its requirements and its next step.

So basically what i am trying to make is that lets say i have a module which is responsible for procesing if a user is still in the payrolle of a given user group.
For the sandbox user i need to make a UI which he can freely configure the element and trow it any way in any number in the workflow.

Now here is the one thousand question. Which coding pattern should i use to make that possible. I have few in mind but i am searching for a better solution atm.

one i am roughly wanting to implement somthing like this one:
http://www.workflowpatterns.com/patterns/control/advanced_branching/wcp9.php

But have few ideas how to acomplish it. I am thinking should i implement a n-tier structure which is very footprint heavy for the coder aka many repetitions.
or a MVC structure which also not a best solution...

Somthing like a factory patern enforced via interfacce regulation should be adequate but i am searching for somthing with more logic in its structure. Somthing like a state aware infrastructure.

For the implementation i am using for the front end extjs, and for backend im planing zend 2 with Ext.Direct

Comment: do you have any concrete in php in mind? i looked up http://ezcomponents.org
and it  looks promising.

Comment: Have read trough the abstract factory patern, and it s a part solution for the interaction.Now i only need a solution for the state dependacy between the objects trough the workflow

Comment: you can bodge together an object state reference/lookup table using either sql or memcached something like that as your storage engine, using your factories to create the structure on the fly for each workflow interaction point.  Something to be aware of is that workflow systems like this are massively complex and have had millions of pounds and man hours poured into them by large companies perhaps its better you working on some more limited work flow cases which give the user appearance of full flexibility but in reality are more just a series of cases vs status from experience its complex :)

Comment: I am working corrently on a project which is on end of life, and it is made exacly as you described it. but we are becoming a bigger company which requires more and more complexity and the if else case statments are driving us to endless hours of  maintainance. Which is at this point that our code base is on 1000 mil lines of if else while idiocy, i am now trying to make a skeleton for a new aplication settup which should take over over our old system.

Comment: sooo yeah that idea to keep it simple drove us in the corner with maintainability. we need a new skelet structure for future projects. Now even a simple change like a new checkbox is making 50h+ Hours

Comment: Yeah I assumed you were working on a typical small scale web app. factories and constructors and abstraction are definately the way forward for you then I'd personally couple it with an object storage memcached for storing the properties of each object in when you retrieve the object out its then piped through the correct workflow factory based off its properties and then outputted back to wherever object/db/memcached etc and then use periodic write back to commit your object store to a db as a light outs backup point so you don't loose object data in temp storage in case of failure

Comment: This is interesting reading http://www.workflowpatterns.com/patterns/presentation/abstractsyntax/index.php on the theoretical side at least

Comment: Thank you soo much for the info. will think of somtihng. I wil need to implement a standard across all elements so no confusion can happen. And i NEED to implement limits so the damn thing dous not get programmed wrongly.

Comment: Good luck you've got a massive project infront of you even with a decent sized dev teams its going to be hard work will take an awful lot of planning. (personally i'd not use php either!)

Comment: Thank you. I am considering to change to Java. But have to little experience in it, so i am sticking to php for now.  Also this is still only an brainstorming session. Thank you very much for the input.

Comment: I'd avoid java too tbh.  If I was doing something like this I'd run with php for front end / display and have a C# process back end for running the actual workflows when triggered from the web front end.  I much prefer c# to java for all real-world usage patterns where performance is required though don't want to say it too loud the java trolls will all come out

Comment: Beware the trolls, dont feed them. Thank you for the inspiration :D